# Python KIVY : CANNOT IMPORT NAME 'App' FROM 'Kivy.app'

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, kivy, kivy-language

[image: Python kivy: cannot import name 'App' form 'kivy.app']

I'm new at kivy, and I follow all the instructions on the kivy documentation but still it shows me errors like this. I also watch and google a solution for this but it always throw me errors, do you have any solution for this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That error seems to indicate that Kivy is there, but app.py doesn't contain an App class. I don't know why that would be, it's quite a strange problem given everything else seems to be in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace python.exe with pythonw.exe in your interpreter, this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

First 
"import kivy",
 followed by 
"from kivy.app import App"
You can check the link:

https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.app.html#creating-an-application